# Using Key management server in application

Tags: java, python, scala, encryption, cryptography

I am working on application where I need to encrypt data stream(I receive data from some server) and then save encrypted stream to some server.
Whenever client will ask for particular data stream(data stream will be time based, like user want to see data from 10:15 to 10:20 on 3rd May, 2015), I will be sending them encrypted data stream and key to decrypt this stream.

I am thinking to use any open source Key Management Server which can provide java/scala/python API to generate keys.
Key management system should have following capabilities:
1. Generate a new key on demand.
2. Remember what key was provided at which time and to which client, based on this provide old key.
3. Maintain all provided keys with details(client ID, time when key was provided, request ID)
4. Delete old key database if required.

If anyone has worked on same scenario, please let me know.
Please suggest if it is good idea to develop key management server based on above requirement instead of using already developed server.